# MySQL tables do not show when trying to export my schema... What do I do?

Tags: mysql, database, export, database-schema, workbench

[the screenshot of MySQL export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgIyf.jpg)MySQL tables do not show when trying to export my schema...
I can see those tables in my schema, etc but not when trying to export. What could be wrong? I am using MySQL Workbench on MacBook Air if that helps.
Thank you!!!

I don't know what to try.

Comment: Is there any prompt or error when exporting

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no screenshot of the data export screen, I am not sure if I am going to give you the right answer, but make sure you select the schema inside the "Tables to export" tab along with making sure that you selected "Dump structure and data" or "Dump structure only".

Comment: yeah, I have those selected... smth must be wrong with my schema that I created...

Comment: Make sure your schema name is all small letter, this is a known issue with Workbench on mac

Answer (score 0):

Is your schema name all using lowercase? I had the same issue on my schema name with mixed uppercase but tables will show for schema using lowercase only. This is a bugs on MySQL Workbench since long ago (Refer this link https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103783). Seems like still not fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround por this issue is export the DB by terminal.

This video helps me whit that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j0BKf-rvoM

Just to clarify:

- Maybe the route to mysqldumb it's different, something like "/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.2.0_1/bin/mysqldump".
- In the part like "punith > punith.sql", the first part it's the database name and the second one it's the name you want for the sql file.
- The password it's the one for your database, not your device.
- The final file will be in the user's folder.